# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid argument

Tags: java, sql, database

I"m running into an error with some code that gets information from an MS Access Database.

Here is the SQL statement that i use to load the information from the database

```
SELECT * FROM tblIRPolicyInfromation WHERE (((StatusID)='I34C28AF3567FFE37B5FAB2FB73210DE1System201209031224'));
```

this generates the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid argument.
```

Running the code directly in MS Access produces no errors and other then the table name being too long. The error makes it seem that it has something to do with the where part. No idea though i could be completely wrong on that front.

Comment: Update with full stack trace :) will be handy to all @theNewb

Comment: @thenewb what makes you think it is referring to the where clause?

Comment: Try removing all of the parens from the where clause - they're not needed, and I suspect that "(StatusID) = " instead of "StatusID = " is causing your problem. Also, what do you mean by 'table name being too long' ?